# Azure Storage billing for deleted blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am planning to place some data on Azure Storage, let's say 10 GB. But blobs will be there only for days and will be removed before the invoice comes in. When removed, I will have 0 bytes left in storage.

Is 10 GB going to be billed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/storage/

> FAQ
>
> If I use Storage for only a few days a month, is the cost prorated?
>
> Yes. Storage capacity is billed in units of the average daily amount
>   of data stored, in gigabytes (GB), over a monthly period. For example,
>   if you consistently utilised 10 GB of storage for the first half of
>   the month and none for the second half of the month, you would be
>   billed for your average usage of 5 GB of storage.